# Find the Fourier transform the function

Tags: fourier-transform

The given function is $$f(x) = ({a - |x| , |x| < a})$$
and hence deduce that $$\int_{0}^{\infty} \left(\frac{\sin(2t)}{t}\right)^2 dt = \frac{\pi}{2}.$$
Can anyone please solve this?

Comment: I am not going to solve this for you, but below there is a hint which I hope will help you. Now it's your turn!

Answer (score 1):

Note that $f(x)=\max\{0,a-|x|\}$. According to the definition of [Fourier transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_transform#Definition), you have to evaluate
$$\hat{f}(\xi)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x)e^{-ix\xi}dx=\int_{-a}^a(a-|x|)e^{-ix\xi}dx.$$
Then, in order to deduce the integral, 
$$\int_{0}^{\infty} \left(\frac{\sin(2t)}{t}\right)^2 dt=
\frac{1}{2}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \left(\frac{\sin(2t)}{t}\right)^2 dt=
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \left(\frac{\sin(s)}{s}\right)^2 ds$$
consider the inverse Fourier transform:
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\hat{f}(\xi)e^{ix\xi}d\xi=2\pi f(x).$$
Can you take it from here?